Laravel | Don't load relations were mentioned in protected $with = [];
I have a query:
$users = User::query()->with([‘relation’])->get();

A relation described in User model:
public function relation(): MorphTo
{
    return $this->morphTo(__FUNCTION__, 'object_type', 'object_id');
}

Code: $users->first()->relation could return different models as it’s Polymorphic Relationships, each model could have different Eager Loading by Default.
class Book extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['authors', 'publications'];
}

class Magazine extends Model
{
    protected $with = ['shops'];
}

How to avoid loading these relations were defined in each model in protected $with = [];?

Have you tried using a function for your main eager load? e.g.: ->with(['relation' => function (MorphTo $morphTo) { $morphTo->morphWith([...]). ref. Btw you're referring to L11 docs but your question is for L10

I tried, It's very useful when you have MorphTo relation and depends on model you'd like to load different relations, as some model couldn't have:
$morphTo->morphWith([Post::class => ['user']]);. In my case I wouldn't like to load relations were predefined in protected $with = [];

have you tried the ->without('relation.authors', 'relation.publications', 'relation.shops') ?  here is the docs.

Yeah, I also tried this variant, but it doesn't work. Interestingly, when I looked at the loaded relationships, I see these relationships: 'relation.authors', 'relation.publications', 'relation.shops', and it seemed that the without method should work, but it doesn't.
